# Registering displayName with ServiceStack's ServerEventsClient before invoking Start

Tags: c#, servicestack, server-sent-events

I am developing a small chat implementation in my app and I want to be notified when someone has joined/left the channel and who that person is.

On the client side I am listening to `OnJoin` and `OnLeave`, which take a `ServerEventCommand` object, in order to showcase the message, but the `ServerEventCommand` object is populated with some seemingly random properties on the server side after I have registered on the client side.

I'm looking into the `ServerEventsClient` object and all of its properties but cannot find a way for me to set the properties I want before invoking `Start()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `displayName` isn't a property you set, it's sent by the server to identify which users are joining/leaving the channels you're subscribed to. It will either contain the `UserName` of the User or if your Auth Provider doesn't use UserNames (e.g. Uses Email or id number instead) it will use the `DisplayName` property of the Users Session.

You need to register event handlers in your [Server Events Client](https://docs.servicestack.net/server-events#server-event-clients) before calling `.start()`, e.g using the [TypeScript ServerEventsClient](https://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-server-events-client):

```
const channels = ["home"];
const client = new ServerEventsClient("/", channels, {
    handlers: {
        onConnect: (sub:ServerEventConnect) => {  // Successful SSE connection
            console.log("You've connected! welcome " + sub.displayName);
        },
        onJoin: (msg:ServerEventJoin) => {        // User has joined subscribed channel
            console.log("Welcome, " + msg.displayName);
        },
        onLeave: (msg:ServerEventLeave) => {      // User has left subscribed channel
            console.log(msg.displayName + " has left the building");
        },
    }).start();
```

Only after you've started your subscription and are subscribed to your channel will you receive any events.

### Channel Subscribers

Most Server Event Clients also allow you fetch a list of Users, e.g. with the TypeScript client you can call `getChannelSubscribers()`:

```
client.getChannelSubscribers()
    .then(users => users.forEach(x => 
        console.log(`#${x.userId} @${x.displayName} ${x.profileUrl} ${x.channels}`)));
```

Alternatively you can call `/event-subscribers` directly to fetch the list of users in each channel, e.g:

```
$.getJSON("/event-subscribers?channels={{ channels }}", function (users) {
});
```

### Example Chat Apps

For reference there are a number of simple Apps written in different languages which uses the different Server Event Clients available to create a simple Chat App:

#### [JavaScript Client](https://docs.servicestack.net/javascript-server-events-client)

- Chat https://github.com/NetCoreApps/Chat
- React Chat https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/ReactChat

#### [TypeScript Client](https://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-server-events-client)

- Web, Node.js and React Native Chat https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/typescript-server-events

#### [C# Server Events Client](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-server-events-client)

- Xamarin.Android Chat https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/AndroidXamarinChat

#### [Java Client](https://docs.servicestack.net/java-server-events-client)

- Android Java Chat https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/AndroidJavaChat

Comment: Since I was using jwt as means of authentication, I added EventStreamRequestFilter = req => { req.AddBearerToken(Jwt); } to my ServerEventsClient before invoking Start() and all works well! I now have my username and userId as part of `ServerEventCommand` objects. I have a minor problem though. I did it successfully in C# client, but can't find that method anywhere in TS client or anything that resembles it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MladenRistic Have a look at the [Send JWTs in HTTP Params](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#send-jwts-in-http-params) and setting JWT Cookie example.

Comment: All works well now! A classic example of not fully reading the docs... Thank you very much for your support and patience, it must have been a drag to answer a question that has a clear explanation in the docs!